# Unlinking files and directories in PHP

Tags: php, directory

The following code successfully removes sub directories and the files within them.

However it also removes all files in the directory above what is specified as $dir.  This is not desired.

Can anybody see what is wrong with the code?

```php
    private function unlinkPubDirectory() 
    {
        $dir = DIR_DOWNLOAD_PUB;
        $h1 = opendir($dir);
        while ($subdir = readdir($h1)) {
            $h2 = opendir($dir . $subdir);
            while ($file = readdir($h2)) {
                @unlink($dir . $subdir . '/' . $file);
            }
            closedir($h2); 
            @rmdir($dir . $subdir);
        }
        closedir($h1);
    }
```

Comment: Using `@` you're just suppressing the errors and nothing else. Note : This doesn't answers the question

Comment: First remove your @ then you'll be able to see what's wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As marked in the comments you should check for '..' as a possible file/directory and omit it. Additionally, check for errors without the '@'-sign.

```
private function unlinkPubDirectory() 
{
    $dir = DIR_DOWNLOAD_PUB;
    $h1 = opendir($dir);
    while ($subdir = readdir($h1)) {
        if ($subdir == '..') continue; // don't do anything with '..'
        $h2 = opendir($dir . $subdir);
        while ($file = readdir($h2)) {
            unlink($dir . $subdir . '/' . $file);
        }
        closedir($h2); 
        rmdir($dir . $subdir);
    }
    closedir($h1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show you what is being deleted

```
while ($subdir = readdir($h1)) {
    $h2 = opendir($dir . $subdir);
    while ($file = readdir($h2)) {
        echo "<p>will remove file " . ($dir . $subdir . '/' . $file);
        }
    closedir($h2); 
    echo  "<p>will remove dir " . ($dir . $subdir);
}
```

HINT: check for . or .. folders and ignore them